# How to handle button action in java fx 8?

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

[image]

Here i want, if i wrote something on textarea and then click on button then the label will change as what i typed. But i can't handle the code properly.
Here is my source code---
ClickDemo.java-

```
package Application;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ClickDemo extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        // Path to the FXML File
        String fxmlDocPath = "src/View/sample1.fxml";
        FileInputStream fxmlStream = new FileInputStream(fxmlDocPath);

        // Create the Pane and all Details
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load(fxmlStream);

        // Create the Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        // Set the Scene to the Stage
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // Set the Title to the Stage
        stage.setTitle("A SceneBuilder Example");
        // Display the Stage
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Sample1Controller.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Dell
 */
public class Sample1Controller {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @FXML
    private Button btn;
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TextArea textarea;

    @FXML
    void btn1handle(ActionEvent event) {

        // label.setText("Hello world");
        textarea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                //System.out.println(newValue);
                label.setText(newValue);
            }

        });
    }

    @FXML
    void textareaHandle(MouseEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Sample1.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="Controllers.Sample1Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="274.0" layoutY="230.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btn1handle" text="Button" />
      <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="210.0" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="233.0" text="This is Text 1">
         <font>
            <Font size="31.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextArea fx:id="textarea" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="121.0" onDragDetected="#textareaHandle" prefHeight="79.0" prefWidth="399.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you have the wrong implementation of the method called btn1handle. You are adding the new listener to the textarea instead of setting textarea's text into the label. The implementation of the method btn1handle could be very simple:

```
@FXML
void btn1handle(ActionEvent event) {
    label.setText(textarea.getText());
}
```